# Square Not Appearing

Tags: ios, swift

I am Programatically creating a square in swift. Below is my code, but for some reason nothing appears.

```
let PB1 = UIButton()
func SetUpPB1() {
    PB1.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)
    PB1.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "RS"), forState:UIControlState.Normal)
    PB1.center = CGPoint(x: 200, y: 200)
    PB1.addTarget(self, action: Selector("PB1Pressed"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.view?.addSubview(PB1)
}
```

P.S I need the setup function or the app will crash.

Comment: Do you ever call your `SetupPB1` function?

Comment: FYI - it is standard naming conventions that variable and function names start with lowercase letters. Class names start with uppercase letters.

Comment: You mean you're programmatically creating a square-shaped button, right? That's much more meaningful than calling it a square. How is setupPB1 called? (From what function?) If it's in your init, the above will fail because self.view will be nil. You need to call this function in `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear`, or `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: @DuncanC It is inside the view did load

Comment: @DuncanC how do I call it

Comment: @rmaddy how do I call the function? I thought I did by writing it?

Answer (score 0):

You said "...how do I call the function? I thought I did by writing it?" That is wrong. Functions don't get called unless you call them - nested functions as well.

If `SetUpPB1()` is a nested function inside your `viewDidLoad` and you only call it once it's probably cleaner to just get rid of it and put that code inline in viewDidLoad.

Otherwise, you need something like this:

```
func viewDidLoad() {
  let PB1 = UIButton()
  func setUpPB1() {
    PB1.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)
    PB1.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "RS"), 
      forState:UIControlState.Normal)
    PB1.center = CGPoint(x: 200, y: 200)
    PB1.addTarget(self, action: Selector("PB1Pressed"), 
      forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
      self.view?.addSubview(PB1)
  }
  setUpPB1() //Add this line to call the function
}
```

Comment: Did you rename your function to start with a lower case letter?

Comment: Think. In the code I posted, I renamed the function to start with a lower-case letter.  (See rmaddy's comment.) You then copy and paste my code, but don't rename your function to start with a lower-case letter. It doesn't work, because the function names don't match.